# The description is not prominent by default; however, some themes may show it

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the latest wp version. When I go to edit a category to add descriptions specifically for each category, there is a note that says, "The description is not prominent by default, however some themes may show it."

My theme does not show it. What code do I need to make this visible/prominent? And where would I insert it?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [category_description()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description).

```
<?php echo category_description(); ?>
```

As for where to add it, that's way too broad of a question. We would have no way of knowing without looking at your theme template system.

Comment: it is a  "Directory template". when i add description in listing category and click on update then it does not store in database and i do not see those description in edit listing category.

Answer (score 0):

To display the category, we want to echo it:

```
<?php echo category_description();?>
```

And you would basically treat this as if it is text (because that's what it outputs).

So lets say you have a `<div>` that you want it displayed within in your theme....

```
<div class="your-container">
    <?php echo category_description();?>
</div>
```

And there ya have it!

Wordpress Codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description

Comment: i want to display desription in admin side in listing categories page.However it is not store in database.

Comment: Ah you didn't give us the full detail in the first question. Make sure you're giving us ALL the information. When you say theme I assume not backend but user facing.